# AD811AN Op-Amp working temperature?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, damage

I want to use AD811AN as high frequency amplifier. According to its [datasheet](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD811.pdf&ei=-ZhUUrj2Leaz0QWX0YCQAg&usg=AFQjCNGC4IL6zbI9Ra7p0uuL5bRrFLG6fw&sig2=SWjbLlpWIjppDP_oqX17tw&bvm=bv.53760139,d.d2k&cad=rja) , Its Absolute maximum V+ and V- are +18 and -18 and differential input voltage is +/-6 V. Most of the graphs in the datasheet are tested in +/-15 v supply voltage.

When I use it with +/-12 Volt supply and input signal= 0-50MHz , 200mV pk-pk (which are all well below the maximum ratings), it works fine but gradually it gets very hot (in around 5-10 minutes) until stops working.

Here are thing I tried:

1- Removed all components until it was just connected to V+ and V- . all input, output and ground connections removed. but it gets hot.

2-Replaced it with 3 other parts(with the same part number ) but they got hot also.

I should mention that after the device gets cool, it works fine again for next 5-10 minutes.

I am sure there must be something that I am missing with this device. Please let me remind that the device gets hot even when just pin7=V+ and pin4=V- are connected to 12V and all other pins are not connected to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This amplifier is designed to operated in a specific fashion with specific feedback resistor values.  Note that the In+ and In- terminals have very different characteristics.  Operating the device un-connected w/o feedback circuits it is unsurprising that it has problems.  To guess what is happening would be just that, guessing.  Connect it up with the recommended values, Do not leave the input floating (it will pick up stray fields and amplify those and chew up more current doing so) and **then** if it's over-heating come back and ask the same question.

These devices can run hot.  the quiescent current (taking worst case @ +/- 15 V) is 18 mA.  This is dropped across 2*12 = 24 V => 0.432 W of dissipation.  in a DIP package it it 90 C/W from ambient 39 C + 25 C (room temp) = 64 C even before it is driving anything.

Comment: OK! I did so. I tried the recommended values in Table-3 of the datasheet ( the availabe commercial values): RF:470 ohms. RG= 47 ohms. VS=+/-12 v. I left it for 25 minutes. It gets hot again but surprisingly did not stop working after 5-10 minutes ! ( it is working 30 minutes up to now). I think this case has become complicated. Although it may seem to "work" but it is obvious that an op-amp which is working hot may not live long!

Comment: Draw the schematics in the original question.  Also indict which part you are using, particularly the the package type.

Comment: Also describe gain, and impedance of load (to determine power driven into load).

Comment: I am using a simple negative feedback design with recommended resistors in the datasheet ( Rf=470 ohms, RG=47 Ohms for a 10x gain). But I noticed in the datasheet that all designs are in positive feedback. I have heard ( not sure ) that these Current Feedback Op-Amps have one input pin with low impedance. If we assume this is correct and that pin is IN+, a negative feedback design may worsen the scenario. Is that correct?

Comment: I saw in your edited answer a good calculation that shows these devices work hot. This is a DIP device and has no connection for heat radiators. Working in such high temperature will not reduce its life span? I contacted Analog Devices technical support but they did not answer my email. Should I put an aluminum sheet on top of the device? I left the device work in 20 volt peak-peak output on a 50 ohms load that gets very hot and left it over night . I is working fine but how long it can work in such high temperature?

Comment: I contacted AD technical support and they acknowledged that it is normal for this device to run hot.